# mysql select increment group row number

Tags: mysql

i had a table like following:

```
OBJECTID            FRUIT
----------------------------
XA13AC              Apple
HAS13X              Grape
UTHQ1G              Orange
YQ1GXQ              Kiwi
OQP1GV              Apple
GPQ1VA              Grape
GQ1GQ1              Manggo
GYX1GQ              Banana
OPI1G2              Apple
```

Table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `FRUITS` (
  `OBJECTID` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FRUIT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Insert into `FRUITS` (`OBJECTID`, `FRUIT`) values
('XA13AC','Apple'),
('HAS13X','Grape'),
('UTHQ1G','Orange'),
('YQ1GXQ','Kiwi'),
('OQP1GV','Apple'),
('GPQ1VA','Grape'),
('GQ1GQ1','Manggo'),
('GYX1GQ','Banana'),
('OPI1G2','Apple');
```

i tried following SQL not working:

```
SELECT *,
             ( 
                CASE FRUIT 
                WHEN @curType 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := FRUIT END
              ) + 1 AS GROUP_NUM
FROM FRUITS 
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
GROUP BY FRUIT
```

expected result:

```
OBJECTID            FRUIT       GROUP_NUM
-----------------------------------------
XA13AC              Apple           1
HAS13X              Grape           2
UTHQ1G              Orange          3
YQ1GXQ              Kiwi            4
OQP1GV              Apple           1
GPQ1VA              Grape           2
GQ1GQ1              Manggo          5
GYX1GQ              Banana          6
OPI1G2              Apple           1
```

trying to group the fruit by name and its increment group_num on different fruit name.

mysql version: 5.6

any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved by:

```
SELECT OBJECTID,
       CASE WHEN FRUIT = @curType 
            THEN @curRow 
            ELSE @curRow := @curRow + 1 END AS GROUP_NUM,
       @curType := FRUIT FRUIT
FROM FRUITS, (SELECT @curRow := 1, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY FRUIT
```

Comment: Without a primary key, the sequence is arbitrary. Likewise for P.Salmon's answer - the problem, as presented, is insoluble.